# How to get a CancellationToken inside TagHelper.ProcessAsync?

Tags: asp.net-core

I have implemented an asynchronous tag helper like this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/authoring?view=aspnetcore-6.0#processasync. I want to pass a `CancellationToken` to any methods I invoked inside `ProcessAsync` but I don't know where to get it. I take a look on both `TagHelper` and `TagHelperContext` classes but no luck. How to cancel any asynchronous methods I invoked inside `ProcessAsync` when a client abort a connection?

Comment: First explain that what do you want. As I understood from your code , do you want to send an email or run some codes based on email?

Comment: The link I posted is a tutorial for creating a tag helper, not my code.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new `CancellationToken` with:

```cs
CancellationTokenSource source = new CancellationTokenSource();
CancellationToken token = source.Token;
```

However the issue is, the underlying `ProcessAsync()` you want to use does not implement a `CancellationToken`. It only accepts a context and an output. Here is the signature according to [Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.razor.taghelpers.itaghelpercomponent.processasync?view=aspnetcore-6.0).

```cs
public System.Threading.Tasks.Task ProcessAsync (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.TagHelpers.TagHelperContext context, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.TagHelpers.TagHelperOutput output);
```

The idea with Tag Helpers is to provide an alias for HTML for ease of use. I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve, but I would move away any logic that requires a `CancellationToken` away from this to a service class instead.

Comment: What I tried to do is creating a tag helper for populating `select` options from a database.

Comment: The approach you are taking sounds too tightly coupled between layers, and testing that should be fairly difficult. What you could do instead is to fetch those options from your database from a repository, push them up to a service, then let TagHelper to only turn your retrieved options into HTML. Piece by piece. This way you are only concerned about turning a bunch of options into tags, which doesn't really need a CancellationToken.

Comment: The repository interface can be injected into tag helper so testing is not an issue but the problem is still exist due to when invoke a repository method to load entries from database inside `ProcessAsync` still cannot pass `CancellationToken`.